# Retrieving from session suddenly stopped working?

Tags: python, flask, session

Recently I've been developing a website on Flask in python for some computing coursework, and I've been using the Session[] function often, but suddenly it's stopped working, I have two pages which move the booking data between them, have I missed something or is there something bigger going on?

I get a "Key Error" every time I try to access the session of anything in the second code snippet.

Code  snippets given below:

```
@app.route("/manager/editbooking", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def managereditbooking():
    if request.method == "POST":

        if "Filter" in request.form != "Filter":

            StartDate = request.form.get("StartDate")
            EndDate = request.form.get("EndDate")
            Filter = request.form.get("Filter")

            app.logger.info(f"{StartDate} {EndDate} {Filter}")

            if Filter == "all" and StartDate and EndDate:
                # Filter by date range
                getactivebookings = f"SELECT Booking.BookingID, Booking.Date, Booking.Time, Session.SessionType, Booking.Extra, Booking.Price, Booking.NumberOfChildren, Booking.NumberOfAdults, Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName FROM Booking INNER JOIN Session ON Booking.SessionID = Session.SessionID INNER JOIN Customer ON Booking.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID WHERE Booking.Date BETWEEN '{StartDate}' AND '{EndDate}' ORDER BY Booking.Date ASC"
            elif Filter != "all" and StartDate and EndDate:
                # Filter by type and date range

                getactivebookings = f"SELECT Booking.BookingID, Booking.Date, Booking.Time, Session.SessionType, Booking.ExtraNotes, Booking.Price, Booking.NumberOfChildren, Booking.NumberOfAdults , Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName FROM Booking INNER JOIN Session ON Booking.SessionID = Session.SessionID INNER JOIN Customer ON Booking.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID WHERE Session.SessionType = '{Filter}' AND Booking.Date BETWEEN '{StartDate}' AND '{EndDate}' ORDER BY Booking.Date ASC"
            elif Filter != "all":
                # Filter by type only
                if  Filter == "Private Hire":
                    getactivebookings = "SELECT Booking.BookingID, Booking.Date, Booking.Time, Session.SessionType, Booking.ExtraNotes, Booking.Price, Booking.NumberOfChildren, Booking.NumberOfAdults , Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName FROM Booking INNER JOIN Session ON Booking.SessionID = Session.SessionID INNER JOIN Customer ON Booking.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID WHERE Session.SessionID = 8 OR Session.SessionID = 9 OR Session.SessionID = 10 ORDER BY Booking.Date ASC"
                else:
                    getactivebookings = f"SELECT Booking.BookingID, Booking.Date, Booking.Time, Session.SessionType, Booking.ExtraNotes, Booking.Price, Booking.NumberOfChildren, Booking.NumberOfAdults , Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName FROM Booking INNER JOIN Session ON Booking.SessionID = Session.SessionID INNER JOIN Customer ON Booking.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID WHERE Session.SessionType = '{Filter}' ORDER BY Booking.Date ASC"
            elif StartDate and EndDate:
                # Filter by date range only
                getactivebookings = f"SELECT Booking.BookingID, Booking.Date, Booking.Time, Session.SessionType, Booking.ExtraNotes, Booking.Price, Booking.NumberOfChildren, Booking.NumberOfAdults, Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName FROM Booking INNER JOIN Session ON Booking.SessionID = Session.SessionID INNER JOIN Customer ON Booking.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID WHERE Booking.Date BETWEEN '{StartDate}' AND '{EndDate}' ORDER BY Booking.Date ASC"
            else:
                getactivebookings = "SELECT Booking.BookingID, Booking.Date, Booking.Time, Session.SessionType, Booking.ExtraNotes, Booking.Price, Booking.NumberOfChildren, Booking.NumberOfAdults, Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName FROM Booking INNER JOIN Session ON Booking.SessionID = Session.SessionID INNER JOIN Customer ON Booking.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID ORDER BY Booking.Date ASC"

            app.logger.info(getactivebookings)
            q.execute(getactivebookings)
            activebookings = q.fetchall()

            return render_template("manager/selectbooking.html", activebookings=activebookings)

        else:

            app.logger.info("Redirecting to booking page")

            BookingID = request.form["BookingID"]
            BookingDate = request.form["BookingDate"]
            BookingTime = request.form["BookingTime"]
            SessionType = request.form["SessionType"]
            Extra = request.form["Extra"]
            BookingPrice = request.form["BookingPrice"]
            NumberAdults = request.form["NumberAdults"]
            NumberChildren = request.form["NumberChildren"]
            FirstName = request.form["FirstName"]
            LastName = request.form["LastName"]

            session["BookingID"] = BookingID
            session["BookingPrice"] = BookingPrice
            session["BookingDate"] = BookingDate
            session["BookingTime"] = BookingTime
            session["SessionType"] = SessionType
            session["NumberAdults"] = NumberAdults
            session["NumberChildren"] = NumberChildren
            session["Extra"] = Extra
            session["FirstName"] = FirstName
            session["LastName"] = LastName

            return redirect(url_for("managerbooking"))

    else:
        try:

            getactivebookings = "SELECT Booking.BookingID, Booking.Date, Booking.Time, Session.SessionType, Booking.ExtraNotes, Booking.Price, Booking.NumberOfChildren, Booking.NumberOfAdults, Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName FROM Booking INNER JOIN Session ON Booking.SessionID = Session.SessionID INNER JOIN Customer ON Booking.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID ORDER BY Booking.Date ASC"
            q.execute(getactivebookings)
            activebookings = q.fetchall()

            app.logger.info(activebookings)

            return render_template("manager/selectbooking.html", activebookings=activebookings)

        except Exception as error:
            return render_template("error.html", error=error)

@app.route("/manager/managebooking/booking", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def managerbooking():

    BookingID = session["BookingID"]
    BookingDate = session["BookingDate"]
    BookingTime = session["BookingTime"]
    SessionType = session["SessionType"]
    Extra = session["Extra"]
    BookingPrice = session["BookingPrice"]
    NumberAdults = session["NumberAdults"]
    NumberChildren = session["NumberChildren"]
    FirstName = session["FirstName"]
    LastName = session["LastName"]

    if request.method == "POST":

        app.logger.info(f"Deleting Booking with Booking ID: {BookingID}")

        DeleteBooking = "DELETE FROM Booking WHERE BookingID = (?)"

        try:
            q.execute(DeleteBooking, [BookingID])
            sql.commit()
            app.logger.info("Booking Deleted Succesfully")

            return redirect(url_for("managereditbooking"))

        except Exception as error:
            return render_template("/error.html", error=error)

    else:

        return render_template("manager/booking.html", BookingID = BookingID, BookingDate = BookingDate, BookingTime = BookingTime, Extra = Extra, SessionType = SessionType, BookingPrice = BookingPrice, NumberAdults = NumberAdults, NumberChildren = NumberChildren, FirstName = FirstName, LastName = LastName)


-------------------------------------------------------------

P.S Yes I know its inefficient, I'm just trying to get the functionality down first.

Thanks everyone, Ben

I've proven that the data is being added into the session by grabbing the BookingID from the session function in the first snippet of code, and then logging it to the log, it just doesn't seem to get out of it before getting a "KEY Error"
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `managerbooking()` view is being called AFTER the first view is called?

Comment: Also, I see that the first code is example is underneath an `else` clause.  Are you **sure** that `else` clause is actually being executed?

Comment: I think we would need to see the whole code.  This isn't enough detail to track down the problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the else statement if being run, as it shouldn't be giving me that error if it wasn't, as the if statement is used to check if a filter has been passed, if not it then runs the managerbooking() view, as the filter button is a separate form to the edit button's.

Comment: Alright I'll attach the rest of the two full pieces of code, i was trying to keep them out to avoid confusing anyone ahah

Comment: Also we need to know the EXACT sequence of input that causes the error.  After using the manager login and clicking "Bookings Report", then what??

Comment: When you're in the booking report page, press the "Edit" button on the far right of the ugly table and it should give you the error page, the only booking right now is one made by one of my lovely friends, ignore the name

Comment: When I use the manager login, then click Booking Report on the left, then click the Edit button in the table, I do not get an error...

Comment: Huh, interesting, let me restart my laptop to see if that's the issue, any chance opera gx could affect it do you think?

Comment: I think it would be enough for you to open a new private/incognito browser window; you shouldn't have to restart your laptop.

Comment: Yeah, probably should have seen that message before I went through a painful windows update, going into incognito fixed it weirdly, but still broken outside of it, I've got no clue as to why though?? any ideas?